# Unable to multiply a cell value using VBA in an If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to see if the value of one cell is close to the value of another cell. I've done this by saying if the value of cell A is bigger than cell B and the Value of cell A * 0.95 is less than cell B (and obviously vice versa) than tell me that the values are close.

However when I write the if statement it comes back with a type mismatch error. As soon as I remove the * 0.95 in the program the error goes and the rest of the code works.

I was wondering if anyone has another easier way to see if the value of the two cells are close or a fix for the way I am using?

Thanks in advance

```
ElseIf Range("H13").Value > Range("F13").Value And (Range("H13").Value * 0.95) < _
        Range("F13").Value Then
    Cells(2 + I, 7).Value = "Close"

ElseIf Range("H13").Value < Range("F13").Value And (Range("H13").Value * 1.05) > _
        Range("F13").Value Then
    Cells(2 + I, 7).Value = "Close"
```

Note: the error occurs on the first line of this code, and the other ElseIf Statement too. The value of the cell range selected is always a number and cannot be anything else

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me (after adding returns in the right places, of course). Can you show your code with the correct formatting, and include the surrounding code?

Comment: I can make your code fail if I have `Dim I as String` - how have you defined `I`?
It's also a lot easier to see where errors are actually ocurring if you don't use single line `If` statements

Comment: What is  the value of the cell when the error occurs (you should check with the debugger). Likely the cell doesn't contain a number and therefore you can't multiply the value. Note that your code works on the active sheet - maybe you expect a different workbook. Also, the cell may contain a string that looks like a number but isn't.

Comment: You should also be able to use one ElseIf like so `ElseIf Range("H13").Value > Range("F13").Value*0,95 And Range("H13").Value < Range("F13").Value*1,05 Then...`

Comment: @Notus_Panda How is this different?

Comment: `The value of the cell range selected is always a number` - a number or text that may look like a number in some locale? What would be the exact value of the cell, as seen on the screen, and what format is assigned to it?

Comment: @GSerg I said OP can use *one* (instead of two) ElseIf, didn't say it's a solution to his issue. If the issue at hand disappears by removing the `*0,95`, the range H13 isn't a number (nor number as text) but this was already discussed.